# ElementryOS only shows desktop background for around 1 mintute after first login

Tags: greeter, desktop, pantheon, graphics

After the first login after booting, the desktop takes about a minute or two to show up, and I can only see the mouse and the desktop background. No dock, programs, or applications.  I am using a 7200 2tb Segate harddrive, a ryzen 5 1400, and a gtx 1060 3gb with NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Same occurred with me, fresh install using elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180130.iso on a HP Pavilion with NVIDIA GForce 1050 and integrated Intell Graphics.

The way I resolved this is when the login screen appears instead of typing the password I have pressed Ctrl+Alt+F1 (F2,F3..F6 will also work), login from console (username, enter, password, enter) and  then I have typed

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

The last line helps sp intel microcode and NVIDIA drivers was also installed. Force shutdown  by holding a few seconds the Power Off button (`sudo reboot now` freezes with a lot of nouveau error messages) and once the system has started again I was able to login into the desktop.